# Pointing to a class without creating an object for ease of access

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

I have a parent class, which is the preliminary requirements for a bunch of tools.

#### Minimal example:

```
class Tools():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class Func_a(Tools):
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.sex = sex
    
    def _func_a(self):
        print(self.name)

class Func_b(Tools):
    def __init__(self, name, age, sex):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.sex = sex
    
    def _func_b(self):
        print(self.name)
```

I then have a map that I use to call one or the other function, depening on some prerequisites

```
CLASS_MAP = {
    "func_a":Func_a("name1", 25, "m"),
    "func_b":Func_b("name2", 100, "F")
}
```

And then to see what's going on:

```
first_class = CLASS_MAP["func_a"]
second_class = CLASS_MAP["func_b"]


print(first_class.name)
print(second_class.name)
```

My question is, is there any way for me to point to the specific class in my dict without actually calling the class and instantiating an object?

Depending on certain constraints, I have to call one of the classes (e.g. Func_a, Func_b ... Func_f) [Total of 6 sub-classes]

I implemented using a bunch of if-else statements, but that was quite messy and a lot of code was redundant between the two.

If my map can point to the correct class, but not actually call it, that would be ideal. Because currently even if I remove`second_class = CLASS_MAP["func_b"]`, `func_b` is still being called from within the map, correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Do you not just want to store the class itself in the dict? `class_map = {"func_a": Func_a, "func_b": Func_b}`, then do something like `first_class = class_map["func_a
]("name1", 25, "m")`?

Comment: that could work, my simple example doesn't enunciate this, but each class has a different number of arguments. Or atleast it can vary. So I would still need some if-else's to create that logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way:

```
CLASS_MAP = {
    "func_a":lambda: Func_a("name1", 25, "m"),
    "func_b":lambda: Func_b("name2", 100, "F")
}

first_class = CLASS_MAP["func_a"]()
```

Where something like `a = lambda: x` is basically a short form of

```
def temp():
    return x

a = temp
```

See also docs about [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda).

The values of the map are therefore function objects which are stored but not executed until the call operator `()` is applied.

Comment: this seems super interesting. Could you elaborate on what `lambda` would do? And why this would work?

Comment: Such a zero-argument function is often called a thunk, especially in the context of lazy evaluation, which is being simulated here. Some languages (e.g., Haskell) wouldn't actually call `Func_a` in your original `dict` *until* you try to use the value of `CLASS_MAP["func_a"]` somewhere. Until then, it's more like a *promise* to call the function when needed.